# syntax_highlight <source_file> | lpr

Tags: command-line, printing, highlighting, postscript

Does anyone know of a simple way to produce the PostScript corresponding to a syntax-highlighted version of a source file that can be piped directly to a PostScript printer?

As the wording of the question above probably suggests, I'm looking for something that I can run from the command line.  I'm thinking of an interaction like:

```
% syntax_highlight <SOURCE_FILE> | lp
```

...with command-line switches as needed, etc.

The best I've found so far is a Unix utility called `highlight`, but it has problems.  The most serious of it is that it doesn't have an option to output PostScript directly.  (Since `highlight` does support LaTeX output, I tried to patch together a script that would automate the process of generating the PostScript file via *.tex => *.dvi => *.ps, but the visual appearance of the final result is awful, much worse than it is for the HTML file that `highlight` generates for the same source code input.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use vim.

```
vim -c hardcopy -c quit /path/to/file
```

This will print the file and quit immediately. By default, vim prints with syntax highlighting.

If you need to print from stdout of some command, you can do this:

```
cat some_file.c | vim -c hardcopy -c 'quit!' -
```

If you want to save the .ps for later, you can do that by adding redirection to the hardcopy command, like so:

```
vim -c 'hardcopy > /path/to/saved.ps' -c 'quit' /path/to/file
```

Vim lets you set lots of printing-related options, so you might want to see [the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/print.html) if you want to tweak it. Of course, there are lots of [syntax highlighting](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html) options as well.

Comment: What about adding `-n -R` flags to such `vim` invocations?
Also I have problem with running this when I have already opened file with another vim (I raised question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/676810/9689 )

Comment: While vim, as far as I can tell, still has that feature, it should be noted that it has been removed in neovim since version 0.9.0.

Answer (score 6):

There are several programs that pretty-print various programming languages to Postscript, which don't require any third-party software to run:

- [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/)
- [enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/)
- [trueprint](http://www.gnu.org/software/trueprint/trueprint.html)

If you are willing to go via LaTeX, you have more options. Going via LaTeX is mostly useful if you want to include code and something else in the same document; otherwise it's overkill.

- [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de)
- The [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package (runs on any LaTeX installation, no preprocessing required)
- [lgrind](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/lgrind.html)
- [source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/)

Answer (score 3):

In Gedit, the standard editor for gnome, you can print to file, choose Postscript (default PDF) and mark on the third tab, to use highlightening, which is off as default, which produces a nice ps-file for me.

And Gedit has a lot of syntax files, to serve many programming languages, HTML, SQL, XML, rc-files, you name it.

Comment: This works, except that for me (gedit 3.10.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.4) the generated PDF is in grayscale, not color.  Also printing directly results in grayscale.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Shawn J. Goff's answer:

You can use the following single-line vim command to create a .ps file from within vim:

```
:hardcopy > %.ps
```

If you prefer a .pdf file, then you can do:

```
:hardcopy > %.ps | !ps2pdf %.ps && rm %.ps
```

Note:

- The `%` is shorthand for the current filename, so `HelloWorld.C` will print to `HelloWorld.C.ps` or `HelloWorld.C.pdf`

Additionally, to change the rendered font, set the printerfont *before* executing the hardcopy command.  For example, to select Courier 8:

```
:set printerfont=Courier:h8
```

Putting it all together, I opted to put the following in my .vimrc file so that I can simply execute the `:HardcopyPs` or `:HardcopyPdf` command (which can also operate on a selected range within a file):

```
set printfont=Courier:h8 "select the font to use when printing
command! -range=% HardcopyPs <line1>,<line2> hardcopy > %.ps && echo 'Created: %.ps'
command! -range=% HardcopyPdf <line1>,<line2> hardcopy > %.ps | !ps2pdf %.ps && rm %.ps && echo 'Created: %.pdf'
```