# Printing files as PDF with syntax highlighting via terminal

Tags: terminal, printing, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [syntax_highlight <source_file> | lpr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/syntax-highlight-source-file-lpr)

I have about 20 Python scripts that I wish to print as PDF. I wish to print them the way GEdit would allow me to, with:

- Syntax Highlighting
- Line Numbering
- Page Headers

Is there any way I can achieve this through the terminal or in any other way which allows for batch printing?

One way is to write a small script to wrap it within `alltt` or `verbatim` and compile it with LaTex. But this seems like an overkill.

I have read the question on [SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/questions/229418/possible-to-print-to-pdf-from-mac-terminal) but all the solutions print the code as if it were a story book; no syntax highlighting or any of the above mentioned requirements. Another [similar question on SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/questions/338165/convert-batch-of-word-files-to-pdfs-in-mac-os-x) uses Mac OSX Automator.

Comment: Given your requirements, a simple wrapper that replaces `FILENAMEHERE` with `$1` in a nicely prepared template LaTeX file doesn't seem like overkill to me; especially given the special packages for source code (see [these answers at `tex.stackexchange.com`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/867/syntax-coloring-in-latex)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `a2ps`. With the `-o OUTPUTFILE.ps` option, it produces a postscript file, which then can be converted to pdf using e.g. `ps2pdf` (from the ghostscript package). Line numbering can be enabled with `--line-numbers=1`. I do not know if the syntax highlighter of a2ps supports recent python standards.

If you prefer the LaTeX solutions, I would recommend the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package.

Comment: `a2ps` is a very interesting package!