# How can I print well formatted code (hardcopy printout)

Tags: command-line, macos, printing

Similar to using markdown on Stack Overflow to create `monospace output`, how can I do that for my programs.

I tried lp filename.txt and was pleasantly please to find that it was able to use the local network printer and print 'as is'

The problem is the output is not mono-spaced.

Is there an quicker option than...

```
1) copy the text
2) paste into a text doc
3) format the document as mono
4) print it
```

I would love to find some option like `lp filename.txt -format=mono` ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [syntax_highlight <source_file> | lpr](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/syntax-highlight-source-file-lpr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a2ps` was the answer.  I installed it with brew:

`brew install a2ps`

Now I can `a2ps myfilename` and it works.

Unfortunately it comes out landscape and if I try to make it portrait it's squished over to the left and tiny, only up taking 50% of the page.
[upate - found fix to this with parameter -1 (for number of pages to find on one sheet - the default was 2)

However as landscaped it worked and the code has the `fixed format` style I was looking for.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the vim editor to pretty print arbitrary files vim can read. Use the following to create a PostScript file.

```
vim \
  -c 'hardcopy > output.ps' \
  -c quit <input_file>
```

If you want a PDF file, add `&& ps2pdf output.ps` to the command line.

You can also write a small script that pastes the current clipboard content into a temporary file, runs vim on the file, prints the resulting file and deletes the temporary file.

Comment: A good option for your vimrc for when you print code is `set printoptions=portrait:n` to print in landscape mode.

Comment: I'm probably not the only one here that wanted to turn off page headers once printing worked. You can turn them off by adding `set printoptions=header:0` to vimrc.

Comment: For HTMl you can do `vim -c TOhtml -c write -c quit <input_file>`

Comment: Oops, that should be `vim -c 'set cmdheight=2' -c TOhtml -c write -c quit -c quit <input_file>`

Comment: @AndyGaskell I've asked a question, please see if you can solve it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315363/vim-prntoptions-wont-accept-two-options-simultanenously

Comment: Vim's default printerfont is too large for many peoples taste.  You can edit it using the following syntax:  `:set printerfont=Courier:h8`

Answer (score 13):

The shortest path here is probably to use `a2ps`, it generates monospaced postscript by default.

You can install `a2ps` with brew, i.e. `brew install a2ps`

Depending on its setup, it will send the output directly to stdout or lp, override with `-o`. Also, `a2ps` recognizes several programming languages and pretty-prints them.

```
a2ps -o output.ps infile.text
```

Use `--pro=color` if color is available:

```
a2ps --pro=color -o output.ps infile.text
```

For HTML output I tend to use `vim`'s `2html` feature.

Comment: this looked great... but I don't have a2ps.  Anyone know how to install?

Comment: That depends on what operating system you want to install it to?

Comment: sure its a mac - osx

Comment: Googling a bit it seems that a2ps has some installation issues on osx. I do not have much experience with osx but `enscript` has been mentioned as an alternative.

Comment: You can install `a2ps` using MacPorts (http://www.macports.org/). I did not have any problem installing it (on Lion)

Comment: Hmmm, I've had to avoid macports as everyone tells me it has a few issues and they all recommend I use homebrew as a more modern package manager which I do

Comment: +1 for this answer.  See my answer for what I actually did using brew.