# printing .cpp file from command line using emacs

Tags: command-line, emacs, printing, source

The goal is to print a set of *.cpp files on a network printer, but... in a way that the (color) printer prints the files like they appear in the c++ editor including the colors and highlighting. And all of this from the command line.

I succeeded in sending all the files to the network printer but they are (of course) all printed in black and white (text) format.

I used : lp -d 'printername' *.cpp

Is there a way to open the files in something like emacs and pass the print command to emacs from the command line?

BTW: I'm on mac OS X.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43520/how-can-i-print-good-looking-code

Comment: Check out an example [here](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/latex/code_tex_example/) of what @Bernhard [speaks](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67093/13136) of. While it is SQL and not C++, the principle should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would be highly surprised if you can do such a thing directly with `lp`. The following is the easiest solution I could think of.

There is a LaTeX package that can help you a lot: [minted](http://code.google.com/p/minted/). You could write a script, that generates a `.tex` file (probably by `\input{}`) and uses this package for syntax-highlighting. Then you compile it, to obtain a `.pdf` with the colors that you wish. Sending it to printer is than the remaining step.

Answer (score 1):

I think [enscript](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enscript) might help you.  I don't use it for code-formatting myself, but I do use it to print timestamps on text files I print.

I have a shell script in my `~/bin` directory that will save it as a PostScript file that I can then print (directly printing, is of course an option).  If that is helpful to you, I have it in a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/ryanaghdam/5103528.  It takes a text file as the first argument (`$1`).

It is not installed on Mac OS X by default, but is available in Homebrew.