# Vim printoptions wont accept two options simultanenously

Tags: vim, printing, vimrc

I want to print my code into a pdf file, and I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43523/115506) very helpful. However, I want the generated pdf without header and with line number.

From the comment and internet, I found I need to add: `set printoptions=header:0` and `set printoptions=number:y` in `.vimrc`, but this two command can take effect when I only add one of them.

When I add two of them, only the last added take effect, for example, when I wirte:

```
set printoptions=number:y                                    
set printoptions=header:0
```

The header is removed but there are no line numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
set printoptions=header:0,number:y
```

Comment: You are awesome.