# Formatting file in command line for printing

Tags: printing, cups, text-formatting, lpr, lp

Whenever I print a text file with the `lpr` or `lp` commands, the words are cut off at the end of one line and continue onto the other; for example,  'understand' would be split into 'unde' at the end of line one and 'rstand' at the beginning of other. Is there a way to justify the text of a file somehow for printing ? I've tried `lpr -p` and `-o media=a4`, and fit-to-page options, but the words are still cut off.

Solutions that worked for me:

1. garethTheRed's `fold`:    `fold -s textfile.txt | lpr`
2. `fmt` command found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25173/how-can-i-wrap-text-at-a-certain-column-size) and [here](http://dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_17.html): `fmt -u -w 80 textfile.txt | lpr` ; note , that width 80 could be changed to whatever you like, but for me this seems to work well enough

Comment: Take a look at tools such as `enscript` and `mpage` to format your text prior to passing it to `lp` or `lpr`. [syntax_highlight <source_file> | lpr](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/syntax-highlight-source-file-lpr/20462#20462). Shown here too: https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fold`.  Extracts from the `man` page:

```
Wrap  input  lines in each FILE (standard input by default), writing to
standard output.

-b, --bytes
   count bytes rather than columns

-c, --characters
   count characters rather than columns

-s, --spaces
    break at spaces

-w, --width=WIDTH
    use WIDTH columns instead of 80
```

Use `fold` (maybe using the `-s` option so that it doesn't break your lines mid-word) to set your document to about 80 characters wide and print:

```
fold -s myfile.txt | lpr
```

Or, to save the formatted version:

```
fold -s myfile.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: also nice is that the 80 char interpretation includes printable consideration of the effects of returns/backspaces/tabs and etc w/ `fold`.

Comment: Thank u so much! I've been looking for solutions for days!